# LightSwitch - getting an AutoCompleteBox with FindControl, becomes null on cast

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch, findcontrol, autocompletebox

I'm trying to access an `AutoCompleteBox` on one of my screens.  I can see that `FindControl()` has located the control when I do `var testControl = FindControl("MyControl");`

However, when I attempt to cast this to the type of control it is supposed to be so I can manipulate it, the result is `null`.

This is what I'm doing:

```
System.Windows.Controls.AutoCompleteBox testBox = new System.Windows.Controls.AutoCompleteBox();
testBox = testControl as System.Windows.Controls.AutoCompleteBox;
```

`testBox` will be null.

It definitely says the control is an `AutoCompleteBox` on the screen, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Can anyone help?

EDIT: Thanks to Yann, I was able to resolve this with the following code:

```
this.FindControl("MyControl").ControlAvailable += (p, e) =>
        {
            //For every  use I can just cast like ((System.Windows.Controls.AutoCompleteBox)e.Control)
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object you get from `FindControl` is just a just *proxy* object, as you've discovered. The way to *get at* the *real* control is done in two steps:

1. Add code to the **screen**'s `Created` method (the control is not guaranteed to be available until the screen's `Created` method runs).
2. Then add a handler to the proxy's `ControlAvailable` method.

```vb
Private Sub ScreensName_Created

      FindControl("ControlsName"). AddressOf ControlsName_ControlAvailable

End Sub

Private Sub ControlsName_ControlAvailable(sender as Object, e as ControlAvailableEventArgs)

    'do whatever you want in here
    'you can cast e.Control to whatever is the type of the underlying Silverlight control.

End Sub
```

Of course, you need to replace "ScreensName" & "ControlsName" with your own names.

(For some reason, I wasn't able to sucessfully format the entire text of two methods as code)

Comment: OP has C# tag. Since your code is in VB, the formatting code got confused. I submitted an edit with a [prettify tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify) to override the formatting. +1 great answer.

Comment: I actually saw the answer before it was reformatted but have only just got around to replying, sorry.  I don't really code in VB, however I was able to understand your code.  For anyone interested, I believe I have managed to work out the C# equivalent (it seems to work at any rate), I've edited it in to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

If `as` returns null, you're trying to cast to the wrong type. I oother words, `testControl` is not of type `AutoCompleteBox`.

Put a breakpoint on that second line and see what type `testControl` really is at runtime.

Comment: A '[Microsoft.LightSwitch.Presentation.Implementation.ContentItemProxy' apparently.  I have no idea what this is, the control is most definitely an AutoCompleteBox in the screen, and it says it is in the Design View.